# C++ - std::condition_variable notified by different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to notify an event from two different threads. Main thread wakes up on first `notify_one()` call but not on the second one. Is this the right way to use condition variable?

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

bool is_ready_1(false);
bool is_ready_2(false);
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;

void test1()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    is_ready_1 = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}
void test2()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(6));
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    is_ready_2 = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(test1);
    std::thread t2(test2);

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    while (!is_ready_1)
    {
        cv.wait(lk);
        if (is_ready_1)
            std::cout << "Spurious wake-1 up!\n";
    }

    while (!is_ready_2)
    {
         cv.wait(lk);
         if (is_ready_2)
         std::cout << "Spurious wake-2 up!\n";
    }
    t1.join(); 
    t2.join();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: @OlivierSohn Wrong, that constructor also locks the mutex.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Oups let me read the doc again :), then the second part of my comment applies

Comment: @SombreroChicken, there is a bug, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Deleted my comments as my diagnostic was wrong. @SombreroChicken your deleted answer was the right one (but since the question has been edited, now it is bug-free I think).

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok, then I delete my answer

Comment: @JHBonarius -- no; calling either of the notify functions while holding the lock is just fine. A waiting thread won't run until the mutex is released, but there's no problem with releasing the mutex after the call to notify. In this code, the mutex is released by the destructor of the `lk` object when the test function returns. Inside the `wait` call, once the notify triggers a thread, the code locks the mutex, which can mean waiting until the mutex has been released. After it locks the mutex, `wait` returns and the waiting thread resumes execution.

Comment: The code compiles and runs OK for me: [live example](http://rextester.com/PZEF80434)

Comment: @JHBonarius You should notify while mutex is held to maintain fair queuing. Otherwise another thread may reap that notification before the queued up threads. It is poor advice to unlock the mutex before notifying.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin. I will delete the comment. But I got it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). Poor advice from that source??

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin do you have a link to any elaboration or an example of how release mutex before notifying variable may hinder fair scheduling, because I cannot figure out in which cases that would happen

Comment: @pqnet https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one: _Notifying while under the lock may nevertheless be necessary when precise scheduling of events is required_.

Comment: @pqnet http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html: _however, if predictable scheduling behavior is required, then that mutex shall be locked by the thread calling pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal()._

Comment: For clarification, in the initial question, there was a bug : `std::thread t2(test2);` was `std::thread t2(test1);`, but it was edited since so it doesn't make any sense now...

Comment: This question makes no sense now, as the code is fine (except spurious wakeup is when the condition is false). Waste of time. Voting to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Note that a condition variable accepts a predicate that first checks if the the condition is met, and then takes the lock. When you notify the variable, it runs the predicate (without taking the lock), if the condition is true,  the thread will own the lock else the calling thread will keep waiting for the next notification.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

auto is_ready_1=false;
auto is_ready_2=false;
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;

void test1()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    is_ready_1 = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}
void test2()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(6));
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    is_ready_2 = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(test1);
    std::thread t2(test2);

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, [] {
        if (!is_ready_1)
        {
            std::cout << "Spurious 1" << std::endl;
        }
        return is_ready_1;
    });
    //preceding line must clear before this is executed
    cv.wait(lk, [] {
        if (!is_ready_2)
        {
            std::cout << "Spurious 1" << std::endl;
        }
        return is_ready_2;
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    system("pause");
}
```

Also on Windows 10, I see two spurious wakeup events, I suspect these happen when the thread is woken up from sleep.